# gpa calculator LCV infinite loop issue C++

Tags: c++, loops

I am trying to run a loop to calculate GPA, and the loop is supposed to end when the input "No" is entered. However, I continue to output an infinite loop. Does anyone have an idea as to why my loop is not ending?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
int main(){
    cout<< std::fixed << std::setprecision(2);
    string grade;
    float gpa;
    string course;
    string answer = "Yes";
    string answer2= "No"
    int credits;
    int totalCredits = 0;
    double totalG = 0;
    double totalGpa = 0;
    double x = 0;

    while(answer == "Yes"){
    cout<<"Enter a course name: ";
    getline(cin, course);
    cout<< course << endl; 

    cout<< "Enter number of credits: ";
    cin>> credits;
    cout<< credits << endl;

    cout<< "Enter your grade (A, B, C, D, F): ";
    cin>> grade;
    cout<< grade << endl;

    cout<< "Continue 'Yes' or 'No'? ";
    cin>> answer;
    cout<< answer << endl;

    if(answer != "Yes"){
        cout<< "Continue 'Yes' or 'No'? ";
        cin>> answer2;
        cout<< answer2 << endl;
    }
    }

    return 0;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

First, add a semicolon in line number 12

```
string answer2="No";
```

Second, your loop issue,
The loop you are using is While loop. Its is declared in While as, if the answer answer is Yes then do this. But, at the end of the code inside the while loop, you are asking it to do something else which will automatically be done when the While exits.

So, I made this edit,
Try this.
This works for me.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    cout<< std::fixed << std::setprecision(2);
    string grade;
    float gpa;
    string course;
    string answer = "Yes";
    string answer2= "No";
    int credits;
    int totalCredits = 0;
    double totalG = 0;
    double totalGpa = 0;
    double x = 0;

    while(answer == "Yes")
    {
        cout<<"Enter a course name: ";
        cin>> course;
        cout<< course << endl;

        cout<< "Enter number of credits: ";
        cin>> credits;
        cout<< credits << endl;

        cout<< "Enter your grade (A, B, C, D, F): ";
        cin>> grade;
        cout<< grade << endl;

        cout<< "Continue 'Yes' or 'No'? ";
        cin>> answer;
        cout<< answer << endl;
    }

    if(answer != "Yes")
    {
        return 0;
    }
}
```